# AppEngine server cannot import atom module

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I have gdata library install on my ArchLinux, and a simple application which imports atom library at the beginning, when I run gapp engine and access that web app,

> $ python2.5 ./dev_appserver.py ~/myapp

It throws exception 'No module named atom'. But when I run 'import atom' in Python2.5 interactive mode, it works well. How can I import atom module in my GAppEngine applications?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Add atom.py to the same directory you keep you GAE Python sources in, and make sure it's uploaded to the server when you upload your app. (The upload happens when you do `appcfg.py update myapp/` unless you go out of your way to stop it; use the `--verbose` flag on the command to see exactly what's being uploaded or updated).

(Or, if it's a large file, make a zipfile with it and in your handler append that zipfile to sys.path; see [zipimport](http://code.google.com/appengine/articles/django10_zipimport.html) for example).

This assumes that you have a single file `atom.py` which is what you're importing; if that file in turns imports others you'll have to make those others available too in similar ways, and so on (see [modulefinder](http://www.python.org/doc/2.5.2/lib/module-modulefinder.html) in Python's standard library for ways to find all modules you need).

If `atom` is not a module but a package, then what you get on `import` is the `__init__.py` file in the directory that's the package; so the same advice applies (and zipimport becomes much more attractive since you can easily package up any directory structure e.g. with a `zip -r` command from the Linux command line).

If at any point (as modulefinder will help you discover) there is a dependency on a third party C-coded extension (a `.so` or `.pyd` file that Python can use but is not written in pure Python) that is not in the short list supplied with GAE (see [here](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/libraries.html)), then that Python code is not usable on GAE, as GAE supports only pure-Python. If this is the case then you must look for alternatives that *are* supported on GAE, i.e. pure-Python ways to obtain the same functionality you require.

Comment: This raises an interesting quandary. I'm as confident this answer is correct as I would be if I read the same thing on Google's website. If I'd done the latter, and someone answered with a paraphrase of the "official" answer, I'd upvote. But it seems a bit odd to upvote based on "I trust that Mr. Martelli knows whereof he speaks". +1 anyway, to get the ball rolling ;-)

Comment: "The official answer" is not in one place (zipimport is documented in two places I'm pointing to, third party libraries in one, modulefinder not in GAE docs but in Python docs [and again I give a URL], appcfg.py in yet another, ...) so what I'm doing is synthesizing all needed info in one place, from otherwise-fragmented locations, which seems more useful than just "a paraphrase";-). Anyway, all of this info is easy to experiment with and verify!-) But thanks for the trust anyway;-).

Comment: Sorry, yes, I didn't mean to imply that there exists a single "official" answer which would be better than this. Just that we can be reasonably confident that if there was one, this is roughly what it would say. So I was a bit surprised the answer went 20 minutes without an upvote ;-)