# Python app engine non-standard package import

Tags: python, google-app-engine, import, module, package

I need a non-standard App Engine package named [qrcode](https://github.com/lincolnloop/python-qrcode). It is a pure python lib that only depends on PIL, which is supported by App Engine.

My folder structure is:

```
app
|--- handlers/
|------ my_handler.py
|--- util/
|------ __init__.py
|------ qrcode/
|--------- __init__.py
|--------- qrcode/
|------------ __init__.py
|------------ other lib files
|--- index.py
```

On `index.py` I map to `my_handler.py` and on `my_handler.py` I call `from util.qrcode import qrcode` inside one of the handler classes' get method. The problem is that I get `ImportError: No module named qrcode.main` on the `__init__.py` file.

`__init__.py:`

```
from qrcode.main import QRCode, make
from qrcode.constants import *
from qrcode import image
```

`qrcode.main` is one .py file that is inside the `qrcode` package (to see the whole
package, check the repository linked [here](https://github.com/lincolnloop/python-qrcode))

I already looked and I can't find what is wrong. I'd appreciate your help. Thanks!

Other questions I searched:
[AppEngine server cannot import atom module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1092648/appengine-server-cannot-import-atom-module)
[Import custom package in python google app engine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4878609/import-custom-package-in-python-google-app-engine)
[Importing nested modules in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3929228/importing-nested-modules-in-python)

Comment: Have you added `util` to `sys.path` ?

Comment: Actually there is no need for that since I can access the folders (they are mapped in the app.yaml). I guess I found the answer. Will post now. Thanks anyway =D

Answer (score 0):

The Python path will include the directory where app.yaml lives. If that's where your `app` module lives, then you should use absolute imports:

```
# in index.py
from app.handlers import my_handler

# in my_handler.py
from app.util.qrcode import qrcode
```

Comment: Actually my `app.yaml` lives inside `app` as well. The main problem, I believe, is that for some reason I can't understand the `main.py` file that is inside `qrcode` is not found.

Answer (score 0):

For some reason (I don't know) the package don't know its own name. To make it work I had to remove all references to **qrcode** on the package files. My new `__init__.py` imports became:

```
from main import QRCode, make
from constants import *
import image
```

All .py files' imports needed to be changed and I had to include `PIL` in the `app.yaml` (I forgot that before, but never got far enough to face this error =P).

By now I still can't generate the images, but I have no more import errors, so I guess the question is answered. Thank you!